# Find the index of Manatee.Trello.ListCollection by list name

Tags: trello, manatee.trello

I am try to find the index of a list returned by Manatee but i am unable to figure it out.

```
        var TrelloList = Trelloboard.Lists;
        var XML = Trelloboard.Lists[2].Cards[0].Description;
        Console.WriteLine(TrelloList.IndexOf("Swim Lane"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collections in Manatee.Trello all implement `IEnumerable<T>`.  As such, all Linq operations will work on them.

If you want to find your list:

```
var swimLaneList = Trelloboard.Lists.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == "Swim Lane");
```

If it's really the index of the list you're after, you can enumerate the collection to a `List<T>` and then use the `.IndexOf()` method as you have in your example.

```
var lists = Trelloboard.Lists.ToList();
var swimLaneList = lists.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == "Swim Lane");
// don't forget to check for null
var index = lists.IndexOf(swimLaneList);
```

You might also want to read the [wiki pages](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Trello/wiki) for more information on using this library.